# Select by id and get the name of the attribute on javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to get a a second value of an element to print it out on another div.
This code gives me 'undefined' value. What is wrong with this code? I don't know. What do you think?

```
<select class="form-control"  id="Workers"  value="Select an id">
 <option id="myInput" onclick="myFunction()" name="personname" value="personid">personid</option>
 <option id="myInput" onclick="myFunction()" name="personname2" value="personid2">personid2</option>
</select>

 <p id="demo"></p>

<script>

 function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myInput").name ;
}

</script>
```

Comment: `id` should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that watches the select element for changes - instead of watching for 'clicks' on an option.

```js
// cache these elements you're going to use first
var workerSelect = document.getElementById('worker-select');
var demoArea = document.getElementById('demo-area');

workerSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // 'this' refers to the thing that the method is called on... so - the select
  // console.log(this); // to see select object
  var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  var handle = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-handle');
  var label = selectedOption.label;
  demoArea.innerHTML = "handle: " + handle + " | name: " + label;
});
```

```html
<select id="worker-select" name="readAboutIt">
  <option disabled selected="selected">Select a worker</option>
  <option label="Derek Wood" value="1" data-handle="sheriffderek"></option>
  <option label="John Doe" value="2" data-handle="J. Doe"></option>
</select>

<p id="demo-area"> <!-- output here... --></p>
```

data-attr can be anything you want. `data-color="red"`  `data-my-favorite-food="?"`

Select: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: I need to keep another value. Can I add a "name" attribute and output the name attribute instead of the value?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. But the 'name' is really for a specific thing. You have a bunch of options. If you are storing 'data' as an attribute of an element, you should use a data-attr - or based on the value, revisit the data through association. In your case - data-attr is likely the way to go. I actually don't think that options get 'names.' The name should be on the select if anywhere. I'll amend my answer to show you. : )

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myInput2").getAttribute("name");
```

```html
<select class="form-control"  id="Workers"  value="Select an id">
 <option id="myInput1" onclick="myFunction()" name="personname" value="personid">personid</option>
 <option id="myInput2" onclick="myFunction()" name="personname2" value="personid2">personid2</option>
</select>

 <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: The id must be the same since the option gets the result from mysql/php. All id's must be same. What can I do?

Comment: you should use classes then.

Comment: This should really be an onchange event for the select element as a whole

Comment: I just answered his question (get the name attribute in javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your snippet to work as you want it to.
Note that I removed the ID from both options, it wasent needed for my snippet and you used the same ID for both elements.

```html
<select class="form-control" id="Workers" onchange="myFunction(this)">
 <option value="0">0</option>";  
 <option name="personname" value="personid">personid</option>
 <option name="personname2" value="personid2">personid2</option>
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction(elem) {
  var optionName = '';
    if (elem.selectedIndex > 0) {
        optionName = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name');
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = optionName;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix `id`s in `<option>`s being not unique and maybe try use `.getAttribute('name')` instead of `.name`:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myInput").getAttribute('name') ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here:

- id's should be unique
- you need to use `.getAttribute('name')` rather than `.name`

Here is a version of your code that populates the `<p id="demo"></p>` with "personname"

```
<select class="form-control"  id="Workers"  value="Select an id">
  <option id="myInput" onclick="myFunction()" name="personname" value="personid">personid</option>
  <option id="myInput" onclick="myFunction()" name="personname2" value="personid2">personid2</option>
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myInput").getAttribute('name') ;
}

</script>
```